# Error al manejar decimales

Tags: latino

Al ejecutar este codigo desde mi terminal, cualquier número que multiplique con un decimal dará como resultado 0, esto no sucede en el compilador online de latino, razones?

````
not1 = leer()
escribir ("ingrese la nota 2")
not2 = leer()
escribir ("ingrese la nota 3")
not3 = leer()
tot = (not1*0.4)+(not2*0.2)+(not3*0.4)
escribir ("Nota final:"..tot)```
````

Comment: Te da algún error?